# Computer name will not echo in batch file

Tags: batch-file, deployment, computer-name

I have a PDQ installer which registers 2 DLL files and logs the results to a network share. If I run the PDQ on 1 machine it echo's the computer name fine, however if i run the installer on multiple machines, it only echo's the first name and not the rest.

The batch file is as follows;

```
echo %computername% >> "\\\servershare\software\Admin\IT_Support_Utilities\PDQ Deployment\Logs\agent_logs.log"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /codebase /tlb "Agent.dll" >> "\\\servershare\software\Admin\IT_Support_Utilities\PDQ Deployment\Logs\agent_logs.log"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /codebase /tlb "MySql.Data.dll" >> "\\\servershare\software\Admin\IT_Support_Utilities\PDQ Deployment\Logs\agent_logs.log"
```

The output is below for a run on 2 machines; `WRCREC274` is the name of the first machine. The horizontal line separates where the next batch file begins

```
WRCREC274 

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Agent.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Assembly exported to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MySql.Data.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully
----------
```

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.
Types registered successfully

Assembly exported to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Agent.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Assembly exported to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\MySql.Data.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully
----------
```

Can anyone advise on why the `%computername%` only appears on the first computer it is run on and not the rest?

Comment: Are multiple computers logging to the same log file? Maybe the name is logged, but in between the logs of another computer?

Comment: This batch file is pushed out to multiple computers using PDQ, so each computer will log to the same file. I could have logged to separate files i.e one log per computer, but this defeats the point of looking through one log file to scan for any errors.

Comment: What if logging from one computer locks the file so another computer cannot log his message? Maybe this is happening here.

Comment: If that's the case why would it Only leave out the %computername% and log the rest. I'm stuck :(

Comment: It is not very propable, but possible. And if output redirection does not lock the log file at all, then you could even end up with one logger overwriting the log of another logger. You could extend your log to "name=%computername%", so you can see if only the variable is empty or if the echo gets lost.

Comment: Almost impossible to divine from the three lines you've posted. Since this is being deployed as you say, to multiple machines, it would need to be in some kind of loop. Please show the entire loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys , I have it working now. I simply have the batch file save the information locally on each machine first instead of logging it straight to the server, I can then use the TYPE command to append the info to my server share.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys , I have it working now. I simply have the batch file save the information locally on each machine first instead of logging it straight to the server, I can then use the TYPE command to append the info to my server share.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /codebase /tlb "Agent.dll" >> c:\agent_logs.log


Type c:\agent_logs.log >> "\\servershare\software\Admin\IT_Support_Utilities\PDQ Deployment\agent_logs.log"
```